# How many sequences of $k$ elements in ascending order from a set $S$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose I have a set $S = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. How many sequence $r$ contains $k$ elements from set $S$ **in ascending order** if:

- $r$ contains repetition, i.e. an element in $S$ can appear several time in $r$.
- $r$ does not contain repetition.

This is actually from a programming question in topcoder, and I wonder if there exist formulas to count the number of those sequences, rather than using a brute-force algorithm to count.

Comment: You are looking for [k-permutations of n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) with and without repetitions

Comment: @DPoole If the sequence is not ordered, then it is a permutation. I don't know how to count ordered sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of the problem, let $x_i$ be the number of times the integer $i$ is selected, for $1\le i\le n$.

Then $x_1+\cdots+x_n=k$, so the number of solutions where $x_i\ge0$ for each $i$ is given by $\dbinom{n+k-1}{k}$, so this gives the answer to part one since there is only one way to arrange a given set of integers in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. I just happen to know it is Diophantine equation.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, you can make a recurrence.  If $T(n,k)$ is the number of sequences, $T(n,1)=n$  If the last element of $T$ is $n$, you have $T(n,k-1)$ choices for the first $k-1$ elements.  If the last element is $n-1$, you have $T(n-1,k-1)$ choices and so on, so $T(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i,k-1)$

If $r$ does not contain repetition, once you choose the elements there is only one string, so $n \choose k$

Comment: Milikan: Sorry, I do not get the last line. If the sequence is not in any order, then the number of them is $n \choose k$. In the case I only consider sequences in ascending order, why the number is still $n \choose k$.

Comment: $n \choose k$ is the number of sets of size $k$ selected from $n$ objects.  For each such set there is exactly one ascending sequence without repetition-sort them.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself by talking about sequences that are not ordered.  A permutation is an ordered sequence.  There are $\frac {n!}{(n-k)!}$ ordered sequences of length $k$ without repetition.  A fraction of $\frac 1{k!}$ of these are in ascending order.  This gives $\frac {n!}{(n-k)!k!}={n \choose k}$ permutations in ascending order.

Comment: @RossMilikan Thank you very much, I understand now. Could you explain a little bit more about the sentence "A fraction of 1/k! of these are in ascending order". Where does the 1/k! come from? If the sequence contains repetitions, then there are $k^n$ of them. Why can't I just take $k^n/k!$ for the number of ascending ordered sequences with repetition? Thank you.

Comment: I was still talking about sequences without repetition for the factor $k!$  For sequences with repetition it is not that simple because of the repetitions.  There is only one sequence of all $1$'s, and it is ascending.  A sequence with one matching pair has $\frac {k!}2$ orders, one of which is ascending.  You can't do the division simply.

Answer (score 1):

For the second one (the first one is clear by now I guess) - choose $k$ elements from the set $S$ and arrange them in ascending order - that's it. So, it is $n\choose k$.